# Can't Debug Azure Function - Visual Studio 2017

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I create a brand new project using the Azure Functions tool with V1 of Azure functions:

[image]

I then hit F5 and get the yellow lightning bolt and then an error message:

"`An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = WebScriptHostManager (DelegateActivator), Services = [Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.WebScriptHostManager], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = None, Ownership = ExternallyOwned ---> The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Utility' threw an exception. (See inner exception for details.)`"

[image]

My settings are:

Visual Studio 2017 - 15.6.7

Azure SDK Functinons 1.0.12

Azure Function V1

Azure Web Job Tools - 15.0.40215.0

Azure CLI 1.0.12

Here are my outputs from my VS console:

```
func.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\Stanley\AppData\Local\Azure.Functions.Cli\1.0.12\func.exe'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: func.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: func.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Stanley\AppData\Local\Azure.Functions.Cli\1.0.12\Autofac.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: func.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: func.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: func.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: func.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Stanley\AppData\Local\Azure.Functions.Cli\1.0.12\System.IO.Abstractions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'func.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: func.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Newtonsoft.Json\9.0.0.0__30ad4fe6b2a6aeed\Newtonsoft.Json.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: func.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Stanley\AppData\Local\Azure.Functions.Cli\1.0.12\ARMClient.Authentication.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: func.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Stanley\AppData\Local\Azure.Functions.Cli\1.0.12\ARMClient.Library.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: func.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Stanley\AppData\Local\Azure.Functions.Cli\1.0.12\Colors.Net.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: func.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Stanley\AppData\Local\Azure.Functions.Cli\1.0.12\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'func.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: func.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Stanley\AppData\Local\Azure.Functions.Cli\1.0.12\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: func.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: func.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Stanley\AppData\Local\Azure.Functions.Cli\1.0.12\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: func.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Net.Http\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Net.Http.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: func.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Stanley\AppData\Local\Azure.Functions.Cli\1.0.12\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'func.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: func.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Stanley\AppData\Local\Azure.Functions.Cli\1.0.12\FluentCommandLineParser.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: func.exe): Loaded 'Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly'. 
'func.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: func.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: func.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: func.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: func.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Stanley\AppData\Local\Azure.Functions.Cli\1.0.12\System.Web.Http.SelfHost.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: func.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Stanley\AppData\Local\Azure.Functions.Cli\1.0.12\System.Web.Http.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: func.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: func.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Stanley\AppData\Local\Azure.Functions.Cli\1.0.12\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: func.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Stanley\AppData\Local\Azure.Functions.Cli\1.0.12\System.Web.Http.Cors.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: func.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Stanley\AppData\Local\Azure.Functions.Cli\1.0.12\Ignite.SharpNetSH.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'func.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: func.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: func.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Dynamic\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Dynamic.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: func.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: func.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\SMDiagnostics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\SMDiagnostics.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: func.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Internals\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: func.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Stanley\AppData\Local\Azure.Functions.Cli\1.0.12\Autofac.Integration.WebApi.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: func.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Stanley\AppData\Local\Azure.Functions.Cli\1.0.12\Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers.Generic.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: func.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Stanley\AppData\Local\Azure.Functions.Cli\1.0.12\Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers.Azure.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: func.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Stanley\AppData\Local\Azure.Functions.Cli\1.0.12\Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers.Pusher.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: func.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Stanley\AppData\Local\Azure.Functions.Cli\1.0.12\Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers.Stripe.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: func.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Stanley\AppData\Local\Azure.Functions.Cli\1.0.12\Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers.Trello.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: func.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Stanley\AppData\Local\Azure.Functions.Cli\1.0.12\Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers.DynamicsCRM.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: func.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Stanley\AppData\Local\Azure.Functions.Cli\1.0.12\Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers.MailChimp.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: func.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Stanley\AppData\Local\Azure.Functions.Cli\1.0.12\Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers.Slack.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: func.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Stanley\AppData\Local\Azure.Functions.Cli\1.0.12\Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers.Bitbucket.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: func.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Stanley\AppData\Local\Azure.Functions.Cli\1.0.12\Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers.Dropbox.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: func.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Stanley\AppData\Local\Azure.Functions.Cli\1.0.12\Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers.WordPress.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: func.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Stanley\AppData\Local\Azure.Functions.Cli\1.0.12\Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers.GitHub.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: func.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Stanley\AppData\Local\Azure.Functions.Cli\1.0.12\Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers.Salesforce.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: func.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Stanley\AppData\Local\Azure.Functions.Cli\1.0.12\Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Proxy.Common.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: func.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: func.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Stanley\AppData\Local\Azure.Functions.Cli\1.0.12\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: func.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Stanley\AppData\Local\Azure.Functions.Cli\1.0.12\Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: func.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Stanley\AppData\Local\Azure.Functions.Cli\1.0.12\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: func.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Stanley\AppData\Local\Azure.Functions.Cli\1.0.12\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: func.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Stanley\AppData\Local\Azure.Functions.Cli\1.0.12\Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Common.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: func.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Stanley\AppData\Local\Azure.Functions.Cli\1.0.12\System.Reactive.Linq.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: func.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Stanley\AppData\Local\Azure.Functions.Cli\1.0.12\System.Reactive.Interfaces.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'func.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: func.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Stanley\AppData\Local\Azure.Functions.Cli\1.0.12\System.Reactive.Core.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The program '[15204] func.exe' has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
```

I have tried:
Uninstalling and reinstalling the Azure Dev workload and also the CLI tools
I haven't tried unistalling/reinstaling VS as this will take at least half a day.

I suspect the problem lies with the Azure CLI

I am getting really frustrated with Azure Functions + VS. 
It is an absolute nightmare to get his fcking thing working !

Comment: I have tried it with the same settings with you except the `Visual Studio 2017 - 15.6.7`, my vs version is `15.6.4`. It seems works fine. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwEuM.png)

Comment: How do I revert back to 15.6.7?

Comment: Are you sure the version of your `Azure Web Job Tools` is `15.0.402015.0` but not `15.0.40215.0`?

Comment: Let me check - could it be I haven't installed some components in the Azure developer workload? I have discovered some were unchecked.

Comment: Sorry I just checked and it is 15.0.40215.0

Comment: I think it is possible. What were unchecked?

Comment: I have checked everything except powershell. Still the same issue.

Comment: You could try to update the Azure Web Job Tools to the latest version, for more details, check the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-vs).

Comment: It seems that your problem is within the local Functions Host runtime. Could you please try to find more details on the error? Try searching the default logs location at `<DefaultTempDirectory>\LogFiles\Application\Functions` and the windows event log

Comment: Another thing to try is to start from an Empty Function template

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce your issue, and it's difficult to tell what's causing your problem since the CLI isn't displaying the inner exception. I've filed an [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/456) against our repo, which should enable us to find and fix the problem if it recurs once that change is made. Otherwise, I'm afraid I don't have advice beyond what you've already received: make sure you're using the latest versions of the tools.

Comment: Vladislav - I tried creating a new empty template and then added a function class - HTTpTrigger. Same issue

Comment: What's interesting is that if I use Functions V2 then I have no problems

Comment: I am having this same issue.  v1 functions give the message in the original question; v2 functions work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem Solved !

I managed to debug the source code for the Azure Function Core Tools thanks to Jerry Liu.

The error message turned out to be Newtonsoft related:

```
"Could not load type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.ExpandoObjectConverter' from assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'."
```

So I just ran nuget to the update the source code to the latest version of Newtonsoft.
Then I copied the rebuilt source code to:

C:\Users[MyUserName]\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\1.0.12.1\cli

and it is now working.

Thanks to all involved in helping me resolve this !

Comment: Glad you solved it! Just out of curiosity, right now can you run your source code directly using VS, no need to copy compiled file to cli folder?

Comment: Hi Jerry, yes I couldn't figure out how to get my azure function code to point to the amended source code for Azure core tools so I manually copied my function files to the source code directory. There must be away..

Comment: So it's not possible to run function files directly in VS on your side? With amended core tools in `C:\Users[MyUserName]\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\1.0.12.1\cli` folder?

Comment: Yes, currently it points to that path but I wanted to my function to point to the amended azure core tools source code . I couldn't find out how to do this so in the end I just copied my function project files to the azure core tools source code directory.

Comment: Sorry that I got confused. So your amended core tools is in a different folder? Could you offer more details about how you amend your core tools? `update the source code to the latest version of Newtonsoft` is to update your function project in my opinion.

Comment: I just downloaded it from the source code on git: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/tree/v1.x then ran nuget to get the latest Newtonsoft Package and rebuilt the solution. I didn't update my function project with the latest Newtonsoft

Comment: Really sorry for the late. Seems things work fine in new version, and no need to use amended core tools. BYW, modifying core tools source code may have unexpected risk when publishing project to Azure as function core tools can't be changed online. Also if you want to use cli instead of the one used by VS, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50853396/debugging-x64-azure-functions-in-visual-studio/50854649#50854649).

Answer (score 1):

I had this same error, and traced it down to a discrepancy in the version of Newtonsoft.Json.dll. I resolved it by uninstalling version 10.0 of Newtonsoft.Json from the GAC. (Azure Functions needs 9.0.)

So, in the Visual Studio command prompt run `gacutil /l | findstr Newtonsoft` and then `gacutil /u` on each version of the DLL you find that is higher than 9.0.

If that doesn't work, I suggest running the Azure Functions tools (func.exe) from source. Clone it from `https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/`, **checkout the v1.x branch**, and run the Azure.Functions.Cli project with `host start --pause-on-error` as the command-line arguments and the output folder of your Azure function as the working directory. If you run this in the debugger and set to break on all CLR exceptions, you should be able to track down your problem pretty quickly.

Comment: Thanks for insights Joe, I have determine that my Newtonsoft is the correct one - Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL

Comment: I have downloaded the CLI project but unsure how to get my function to point to the source code and what to the command to execute is. Sorry, haven't really done this stuff before..

Answer (score 0):

Works for me on v2 rather than v1. I had to go into .csproj file and add *AzureFunctionsVersion* to PropertyGroup

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
  <AzureFunctionsVersion>v2</AzureFunctionsVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```