# Debugging x64 Azure Functions in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, 64-bit, azure-functions

I'm writing a C# Azure function via Visual Studio. This function is triggered through blog storage, and the blob is processed using an x64 C++ DLL.

The issue is that the default Azure functions tooling installed with visual studio only has an x86 version of the functions exe (func.exe).

I see at this URL, there are now x64 builds:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/releases

The problem is, by default, Visual Studio is picking version 1.2.0 of the tools on my machine (C:\Users\acardy\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\1.2.0), and I don't see a 1.2.0 x64 release at the URL.

Is there any way to get Visual Studio to choose a different version that I could then patch with an x64 build?

I'm currently running Visual Studio version 15.7.1.

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1.2.0 (aka cli 1.0.13) download links have not been published yet in the release note you mentioned. And VS downloads x86 cli version for v1 functions by default.

So you can download a previous version x64 cli manually and use it to debug. See [1.0.12](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/releases/tag/1.0.12).

**Note**: Visit [cli release note](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/releases) to download latest version(1.x for v1 functions, 2.x for v2).

After downloading this cli, right click your project->Properties, do debug configuration below.

```
Launch: Executable
Executable: yourclifolderpath\1.0.12-x64\func.exe
Application Arguments: host start
Working Directory: $(TargetDir)
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant, thanks, I'll give this a go over lunch. I tried looking at this briefly, but it was crashing when I started to debug, I figured I had the wrong arguments or an incompatible version.

Comment: Yup, that seems to work perfectly for me! Thanks! :)

Comment: This is a day saver! Thank you so much!